# Best chess theory books for beginners

Tags: learning, books

What are the best chess books regarding theory and such for beginners?

Comment: Beginners don't need theory with the possible exception of general rules such as 'control the center' and "don't move the same piece twice in the opening."  There are several threads here on those topics.

Comment: "theory and such" sounds just slightly too broad...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A book often recommended to beginners is [Logical Chess: Move by Move](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0713484640) by Irving Chernev. It contains 33 games with text explanations for every single move.

Dan Heisman also recommends other books in his [web site](http://home.comcast.net/~danheisman/Events_Books/General_Book_Guide.htm), here are a few:

- Chess: The Art of Logical Thinking - Neil McDonald
- A First Book of Morphy by del Rosario
- Most Instructive Games of Chess Ever Played - Irving Chernev
- Chess Master vs. Chess Amateur - Euwe and Meiden

[edit] Here's a [PGN file](http://www.chess.com/download/view/chernevs-logical-chess-move-by-move) of Logical Chess that you can play through using a game viewer like [Scid vs. PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) while you read the book. Or you can just use a regular chess set.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit old, but I cut my teeth on "Chess Fundamentals" by former world champion JR Capablanca. Moreover, it's one of the few books in the public domain, so you can access it online.

Comment: And many of the available editions have errors in the diagrams, which is potentially worse!

Answer (score 2):

To take the beginner up a notch "My System" by Aron Nimzowitsch ... it goes over basics of theory like open files which even a beginner can get a feeling for. This book will move the person to an advance beginner or to intermediate (with practice). The skills in the book are essential. Here is a link to download the classic: [http://www.taflfelag.is/assets/files/Nimzowitsch,.Aron.My.System.(21st.century.ed).pdf](http://www.taflfelag.is/assets/files/Nimzowitsch,.Aron.My.System.%2821st.century.ed%29.pdf)
The sort of companion to "My System" is "Chess Praxis" which gives games to see the applications of the concepts in "My System". That would probably be a next book.
If you want something for the total beginner then something like "A Primer of Chess" by Capablanca
Be sure to learn all the basic endgame mating combinations (queen, rook, bishop-bishop, bishop-knight) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with others regarding Nimzowitsch - I would not recommend that to beginners for many reasons. I would add  to retrodanny's recommendations, I would also add

- Best lessons of a chess coach by Sunil Weeramantry and Ed Eusebi - joy to read

I would start with Logical Chess Move by Move and then move to Best Lessons (above) and then to others.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following :

1. CHESS FOR CHILDREN by Murray Chandler & Helen Milligan
2. WINNING CHESS STRATEGY FOR KIDS by Jeff Coakley
3. THE CHESS KID'S BOOK OF TACTICS by David MacEnulty
4. CHESS OPENING FOR KIDS by John Watson & Graham Burgess
5. THE STEPS METHOD (Learning Chess Step 1 to 6) by Rob Brunia and Cor van Wijgerden

read more [click](http://newchessbasics.blogspot.com/2015/03/5-great-chess-books-for-kids.html)

http://newchessbasics.blogspot.com/2015/03/5-great-chess-books-for-kids.html

Answer (score 0):

A little indirect of an answer here *but* because you mention that you are looking for books strictly for *beginners* I thought this point might be of use to you:

No real theory is needed in the beginning stages of chess.  The most rapid chess improvement to be gained for the beginning chess player will come in the form of chess tactics.  Studying chess tactics alone will result in huge rating gains. Once you reach an ELO of about 1800 then it becomes necessary to start studying positional theory.

It really is a Maslow's hierarchy type of dynamic.  If you match two computers against each other, one with high tactical knowledge and low positional knowledge and the other with high positional knowledge and low tactical knowledge - simulate it 100 times -- the computer with tactical knowledge will still win all the games.

Hope this makes sense :D

Comment: That's true up to a point, but I would say that an ELO of 1300 is more like when to begin learning openings.  In my first USCF tournament, I beat a 1450 player and an 1100 player, and lost all my other games, including to weaker 1300 and 1400 players.  In the games I lost, I was generally in a losing position out of the opening and unable to recover.  Studying openings over the next year brought my provisional rating from 1256 to 1505 to 1653.

Answer (score 0):

[Learn Chess](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983307) by John Nunn is a fantastic book for beginners, do not be fooled by the title

[Build up Your Chess 1: The Fundamentals (Yususpov's Chess School)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906552010) by Artur Yusupov will definitely make you shed your beginner skins!

[50 Essential Chess Lessons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1904600417) by Steve Giddins, a very easy book to read, fantastic

Answer (score 0):

*My 60 Memorable Games* is a great book on so many levels.  There's something in it for everyone, from beginner to grandmaster.  If you want to learn the Ruy Lopez, go over the Ruy Lopez games.  (While Fischer was known for the Sicilan, Sicilian opening theory has changed more than Ruy Lopez since the 70's.)  It's especially fun to go over Fischer's analyses with an engine, to see if his opinions about his games where really correct or not.

While it isn't the only book on chess to read, it is one of the great classics.  If it is the only one you read, you'll still find that it improves your game.

I've seen recommendations for Chernev's *Logical Chess*.  That is indeed a good book, one of the few that explains every move.  When I was a beginner, I often found it frustrating to go through books and have no idea why a particular move was chosen.  If you can get past his gushy style, there's a lot of good insight in there.